# How bad would it be to use HTML5 app cache to cache in EVERY SINGLE file

Tags: html, manifest, html5-appcache

I have a webpage that makes around 150 HTTP Requests upon loading.  I am told to make this webpage work offline by using HTML app cache to cache literally every single file.  That is, every image, HTML, CSS, JS file, and any other files needed to load the webpage.

Never mind that the cache section in the manifest file does not allow me to use wildcards, so I'd have to write down all 150 urls (I can write a python script to do that).  But my instincts tell me this is a very, ***very*** bad idea.

Can someone tell me exactly how bad it is, and why? Or am I just being too paranoid, and this is okay?

Anything will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I'd really look into solutions to combine your CSS, JS resources... regardless of the offline problem

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to touch the original for the website, other than changing <html> to <html manifest="manifestFile.appcache">.

Answer (score 0):

If it must save all data try using some of these techniques recommended by google.

[Minimize request overhead](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/request)